# Meteor User Accounts - Facebook login not showing but Google is

Tags: facebook, twitter-bootstrap, meteor, meteor-accounts, meteor-helper

I am trying to integrate the Meteor UserAccounts Bootstrap package following [this](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core/blob/master/Guide.md#internal-states) guide.

I have set the `ServiceConfiguration` properly for both the services but only Google shows up. I also tried adding Twitter but even that does not work. Does anyone have any idea what I'm missing?

Packages -

```
meteor-platform
accounts-password
iron:router
aldeed:collection2
useraccounts:bootstrap
nemo64:bootstrap
less
accounts-google
service-configuration
fortawesome:fontawesome
accounts-facebook
accounts-twitter
```

Accounts configuration on the server -

```
// /server/lib/config/accoutns.js

    Meteor.startup(function() {
      // Add Facebook configuration entry
      ServiceConfiguration.configurations.update(
        { service: "facebook" },
        { $set: {
            appId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            secret: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
          }
        },
        { upsert: true }
      );

      // Add Google configuration entry
      ServiceConfiguration.configurations.update(
        { service: "google" },
        { $set: {
            clientId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            client_email: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            secret: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
          }
        },
        { upsert: true }
      );

      ServiceConfiguration.configurations.update(
        { service: "twitter" },
        { $set: {
            consumerKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
            secret: "XXXXXXXX"
          }
        },
        { upsert: true }
      );

    });
```

But this is all that comes up -

[image]

EDIT1: I just noticed something very interesting. I cloned this exact project on my friend's macbook and everything is coming up perfectly as expected. (I was using a Linux mint 17 earlier). I think this is some kind of a bug but not sure what is culprit here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be using ublock or adblock on your browser. Simply disable it and it'll work.

Its a bit weird but it looks like while Meteor is unminified it blocks anything with facebook or twitter in its url such as the facebook/twitter packages' js code.

Comment: Ok wow, I did not expect that. I disabled adBlock and it works.

Comment: I'm having the same issues and I disabled adBlock.

Comment: me too. no ad block but facebook login fails. any solution? 
@the-ben-waters